# Convert AM/PM to 24 hours clock in Laravel input field

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

***Problem:*** I'm using laravel forms in combination with Carbon to try and pass a date value to my database. I'm trying to switch the input field format to 24 hours instead of AM/PM, but I keep getting the standard AM/PM format. I tried `->format()` but didn't find the correct solution.

**Question:** How can I replace the AM / PM Format of the input field to the 24 hours clock?

***My code:***

```
{{Form::date('date', \Carbon\Carbon::now(),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
{{Form::time('time', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}

// Input field values:

// Date: 08/16/2018 , Time: 07:47 PM -> 19:47:00
```

**Input result when changing the format:**

```
{{Form::time('time', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels')->format('H:i:s'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}

// Input value of time:
// Time: 08:00:29 PM
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to change your time field to the following

```
{{Form::time('time', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels')->format('H:i:s'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

To explain the formatting;
H - 24 Hour with trailing zeros
i - Minutes with trailing zeros
s - Seconds with trailing zeros

You can see all the date/time variables at [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I edited my post, I tried this format and I still get the PM result

Comment: Are you using any javascript plugins?

Comment: Not at all, maybe the laravel 'time' input prevents it from changing it to the 24 hours clock?

Comment: If you view the source - does it display the time as you wish it to? Also what browser are you using. When I run this on my local environment it works as you expect it to

Comment: I inspected the source, the input value returned:  `<input name="time" type="time" value="20:30:55" class="form-control">` which is correct, both Firefox and Chrome are showing this

Comment: In which case it's either the browser changing it or some js plugin. Which browser does it show incorrectly for? And if you open it in incognito do you still have the same issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178158/discussion-between-dax-and-simon-r).

Comment: This solution doesn't give me 24 hour time picker ! I'm missing anything?

Answer (score 7):

**You Need to use format() method of Carbon instance**

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s') //24 hour format
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('g:i a') //12 hour format
```

OR

```
now()->format('H:i:s') //24 hour format
now()->format('g:i a') //12 hour format
```

`now()` is helper function and instance of Carbon\Carbon

So

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now() is same as now()
```

Comment: I cannot edit your answer, as my edition is too short, but, I assume "14 hour format" should be "12 hour format"