# Laravel how to show date by 24hr time

Tags: laravel

I have a date column in my project which I need to display it in 24hr time

html input

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="registered">
```

how I am displaying it

```
<p> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->registered)->format('d-m-Y h:i:s') }} </p>
```

SQL Structure

```
    registered  timestamp           No  current_timestamp()     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

how can I change it please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert AM/PM to 24 hours clock in Laravel input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882715/convert-am-pm-to-24-hours-clock-in-laravel-input-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp

> H - 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)

```
<p> {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->registered)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s') }} </p>
```